WPF, external styling An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary ""
I have a WPF application where I obtain styling from an external project. The entire project works, but I keep encountering an error in the line of code:
Source="{x:Static local:StyleManager.StyleUri}"

that says: 'An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "'. How can I resolve this error?"
This is my application:
Project: WpfApp
MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

App.xaml
<Application x:Class="WpfApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StylesLibrary;assembly=StylesLibrary"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="{x:Static local:StyleManager.StyleUri}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
    

The external project: StylesLibrary
Styles.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

StyleManager.cs
using System;

namespace StylesLibrary
{
    public static class StyleManager
    {
        public static Uri StyleUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/StylesLibrary;component/Styles.xaml");
    }
}


Is everything working correctly when you use pack://application:,,,/StylesLibrary;component/Styles.xaml instead of {x:Static local:StyleManager.StyleUri}?

Yes, then I don't have an error, but I wanted to have it in StyleUri variable :/

It should work then! The approach is clean, I've tested it. Check out SO posts for "An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary" error message like this one, some suggest restarting VS!

I still get this error after restarting VS, when I have ({x:Static local:StyleManager.StyleUri}). Did you test it on this approach?

Yes, the same exact approach. Anyway, If you can push a minimal app to github then I might be able to inspect the issue for you.

Try to make StyleUri a property instead of a field: public static Uri StyleUri { get; } = new Uri(... related question
